# Why does MATLAB give a negative value for this integration?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-integration

I'm trying do the following integration:

[image: $\int_0^d y^2\sqrt{-y^2+yd}\,\mathrm{d}x$]

where `d >= 0`.

I try to get an explicit expression and I think the result should be a positive value since the integrand is greater or equal to 0, but the symbolic integration of MATLAB gave me this result:

```
syms y d
assume(d>=0)
int(y^2*sqrt(-y^2+d*y),y,0,d)

ans =

-(5*pi*d^4)/128
```

So I am wondering why a negative value appeared. Do you know how to interpret this result?

Comment: I find this absolutely fascinating and would like to know the answer, but I guess the question is better asked in stackoverflow under the matlab tag. Perhaps one of the moderators can transfer it there?

Comment: FWIW, Maple gives $+5d^4\pi/128$, so it seems that it is just the sign that is wrong.  But this seems to be a pure software issue and nothing really to do with mathematics, so I will vote to close the question here.

Comment: Mathematica gives the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help,

Comment: Maybe this is one for http://mathoverflow.net/questions/11517/computer-algebra-errors ?

Comment: (Oops, sorry, I got here from MO and didn't notice it had migrated.)

Comment: Yes, clearly a bug. Tricky!.....   https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11517/computer-algebra-errors/269951#269951

Answer (score 4):

This is very clearly a bug, and I've already submitted a bug report with The MathWorks. You can confirm it by plotting the integrand and noting it is always positive over the range `[0 d]`, thus assuring that the integral should yield a positive value:

```
h = [];
for d = 1:5,
  y = linspace(0, d, 1000);
  h = [h; plot(y, f(y, d))];
  hold on;
end
legend(h, strcat({'d = '}, int2str((1:5).')));
xlabel('y');
ylabel('f(y)');
title('f(y) = y^2*sqrt(d*y - y^2)');
```

[image]

### Update #1:

A response from The MathWorks suggest that this may be an issue with the MuPad command [`limit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/limit.html). Below is the indefinite integral found in MuPad:

[image]

Evaluating this at `y=d` gives the correct result, but evaluating it in the limit as `y` approaches 0 gives different results based on whether `d` is substituted before or after the limit calculation. Here's an example with `d=1`:

[image]

Note the change in sign of the first term. In this case, substituting for `d` before the limit calculation results in a positive (and correct) evaluation of the integral. MATLAB therefore appears to be substituting for `d` after the limit calculation, giving the erroneous negative result for the definite integral.

### Update #2:

I received a follow-up response stating that this bug has now been addressed in the latest release, R2018b. I was able to confirm in the R2018b pre-release that the two limit calculations above produce the same result, and that the integration result now has the proper sign:

```
syms y d
assume(d >= 0)
int(y^2*sqrt(-y^2+d*y), y, 0, d)

ans =

(5*pi*d^4)/128
```